# How to check a memory address is valid inside Linux kernel?

Tags: networking, linux-device-driver, network-driver

i am debugging a corrupt packet content inside Network driver.
I want to dump a packet content inside network driver for debugging.
Before that i want to check whether its address is accessible and valid inside kernel address space .
Any API is available for the same other that NULL check??

Answer (score 1):

I guess, [virt_addr_valid()](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/include/asm-generic/page.h#L92) might come in handy.
As far as I understand, this is merely a validity check with respect to the kernel address space.

Comment: So As i understand the Macro will tell whether the given address belongs to kernel virtual memory or not. I hope it's still in danger if the memory is pointing inside kernel space but to some other process data thereby corrupting that data!! Is my understanding correct?